# jquery effects not loading after xmlhttprequest from the database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, xmlhttprequest

This is my xmlhttprequest so after i some text in the search bar. the ajax works fine. it gives back the information that i want.

```
function ajax_post(){

            var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            var url = "SavingsAddSearch.php";
            var sb = document.getElementById("searchWord").value;
            var vars = "search="+sb;

            if(sb == ""){
                hr.open("GET", url, true);

                hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                hr.onreadystatechange = function (){
                    if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200){
                        var return_data = hr.responseText;
                        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = return_data;
                    }
                }

                hr.send();
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "processing...";
            }
            else{
                hr.open("POST", url, true);

                hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                hr.onreadystatechange = function (){
                    if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200){
                        var return_data = hr.responseText;
                        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = return_data;
                    }
                }

                hr.send(vars);
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "processing...";
            }
        }
```

but after the data was fetch from the database. the problem is the jquery effects like hide and slideToggle can't load. but i know my effects works fine. can someone help me how to load the data using ajax with the jquery effects. my jquery target html is in the php side.